# use raspberry 3+ and PN532 Itead with i2c

Tags: i2c, pi-3b+, nfc

[image][image][image][image]nfc-scan-device uses libnfc 1.7.1

```
1 NFC device found:
error libnfc.bus.i2c error : worte only -1bytes (10 expected)
error libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data(TX)
pn53x check_communication: Input / Output error
error libnfc.bus.i2c error : worte only -1bytes (10 expected)
error libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data(TX)
nfc_open failed for pn532_i2c: /dev/i2c-1
```

I just follow this document
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=78966

5v -> 2 , gnd -> 6, SCL->5, SDL->3

I don't know why It doesn't working please help me ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: @joan I already have done it, but...

Comment: @joan Wait a minute plz I add the photo right now

Comment: @joan I have changed a wiring setting.. plz give me advice.

Comment: @joan How can i set PN532 SET0-->L
SET1-->H

Comment: @joan can you check it please

Comment: @joan OK thanks I will check it now

Comment: Does this I/O board have a 3.3V I²C ? Because the Raspberry Pi has, and **it's not 5V tolerant**.

Comment: Please don't prepend [SOLVED] to the headline. Instead write an answer. That is the right way to present a solution.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

How to setup PN532 NFC for I2C?

***Answer***

It appears that the OP does not have a manual and therefore does not know how to set up the PN532 module:

So I googled the user guide and put it in the reference below.  According to the user guide, the SE0, SE1 switches should be set to H, L.  But the OP seems to have set them wrongly.

***References***

[image: pn532 module 1]

[image: pn532 module 2]

[image: pn532 module3]

Comment: thanks for your sevice, The reason why it doesn't work is setting SET0,SET1

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a nice project.